# Entries from database to dropdown list simple php code

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a material record database.

```
material_records
 poly canvass
 metal
 washer
 knot
```

how to call this entries into a dropdown list.. please help.. i don't know how to call the entries into a dropdown. Happy new year.. :)

Comment: You're question is not really complete enough to be able to answer it correctly. You're database design is vague and you're also not supplying any PHP code to show what you have done.

Comment: Are the indented items values or columns?

Answer (score 2):

Create a query

```
$handle = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "username", "password");
if($handle) {
    @mysql_select_db("database_name", $handle);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM material_records";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $handle);
}
```

Fetch and loop the results and print a select

```
if(isset($result)) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<select name="mydropdrown">';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($handle)) { 
            echo '<option value="blub">'.htmlspecialchars($row["poly_canvass"]).'</option>';
            echo '<option value="blub">'.htmlspecialchars($row["metal"]).'</option>';
            echo '<option value="blub">'.htmlspecialchars($row["washer"]).'</option>';
            echo '<option value="blub">'.htmlspecialchars($row["knot"]).'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select'>;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're example is obviously correct, but I think poly_canvass etc. are rows instead of column names. But, we can only guess..

Comment: Yeah, indeed...
Well bad question quality results in bad answer quality, I dont think this is my fault so Idc. This kind of question says anyway "Please do my dirty work im too lazy to read and learn", dont know im why im soo kind to help out today...

Comment: I definitely understand you bro! Your karma should definitely have increased for this!

Comment: Your row output needs escaping with `htmlspecialchars` to prevent invalid HTML and a possible XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @Up, ye I know i dont want to confuse the author and I did not felt it was worth the effort but if you want I quickly edited it...

*I would never do it this way usually anyway I have a very good MySql handler class for such issues that escapes, encodes and so on me everything before I fetch the results...

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT description FROM material_records";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
                {
                    echo "<option>" . $row['description'] . "</option>";
}
```

This is one of the simplest ways to get the values for your dropdown.

Comment: This needs escaping to prevent invalid HTML, or possible XSS - perhaps `htmlspecialchars($row['description'])`?